# Doctrine2: OneToMany Annontation creates empty DB column

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm, innodb

Though I'm new to Doctrine2 and Symfony2 I know a bit of Zend and thought that my problem is pretty basic, after trying for a few days now, I guess you might be able to help me:

I have two entities: Accounts and Members, with one member can have many accounts and one account always belongs to a member.

What i created is:

```
class Member {

    /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Account", mappedBy="members", cascade={"persist", "merge"})
    */
    private $account;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->account= new ArrayCollection();
    }

    ...

    // the following are set by doctrine: doctrine:generate:entities MMA (my bundle)
    public function addAccount($account) {
    ...
    }

    public function removeAccount($account) {
    ...
    }

}
```

and this:

```
class Account {

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Member")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="member_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="cascade")
     */
    protected $member;

    (with setter and getter)
    ...
}
```

So I expected to get the following DB table:

Table account:

```
id, ..., member_id, ...
```

and for table member I suddenly get:

```
id, ..., account_id, ...
```

Why is there an account_id column? And although I have the methods that column is never filled with anything... What am I missing?

Thanks! Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may have some errors in variable names and 'mappedBy' properties as a result of nomenclature that does not reflect your explanation of the relationship between `Member` and `Account`. If there is a `OneToMany` relationship between the two, intuitively I would write

```
class Member {

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Account", mappedBy="member")
     */
    private $accounts;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->accounts = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

Note the new variable name `accounts` is in plural and the `mappedBy` is in singular `member`. Then for the `Account`

```
class Account {

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Member", inversedBy="accounts")
     * @JoinColumn(name="member_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $member;
}
```

Notice the `inversedBy` property that tells which collection on the `Member` side is being referenced

Comment: right, thanks, i missed that. I changed the variable name to accounts and still i'm getting this column account_id in member, which won't be filled...

Maybe to help clarify the relationship: For one membership one can have several accounts created (logins basically) so you have special membership that can allow you to create 5 different logins, still every login has to be tied to only one membership.

Comment: okay, i had a wrong annotation further down the code and missed that. I'm accepting your answer though, since it helped me figure out some other mistakes i made ;-) Thanks a lot!